# Obter nome do jar executado

Tags: java

Gostaria de obter o nome do .jar que está sendo executado.

Os .jar terão nomes dinâmicos, modificados como algums hash, e gostaria que quando executado, o mesmo identificasse seu próprio nome do arquivo.

O user.dir do System.getProperty me traz o caminho onde o mesmo está, mais como o nome será modificado constantemente, gostaria que quando executado, o mesmo identificasse seu novo nome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente desta forma, conforme [**resposta no SOEn**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11159435/5524514):

```
String jarName = new java.io.File(SomeClassInYourJar.class.getProtectionDomain()
      .getCodeSource()
      .getLocation()
      .toURI()
      .getPath())
      .getName();
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado.